# Calling Adapter from Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have Fragment which have a searchview and viewpager . My viewpager has 3 fragments and each fragment calling adapter . Now to implement searchview , i need to call adapter of visible fragment in view pager .

**SlidingTab(Fragment with searchview and ViewPager):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.RareMediaCompany.BDTrial.SlidingTab">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_job" />

    <com.RareMediaCompany.BDTrial.Utils.CustomTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#f39220"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#808080" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/CitySearchView"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f39220">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/list_icon_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#75aadb">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/mapmarker"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
        <!--android:layout_width="320dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/searchview"/>-->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SlidingTab.class (Implementing SearchView)**

```
public class SlidingTab extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "TabLayout";
    private static String POSITION = "POSITION";
    private Context context;
    private SearchView searchview;
    private Toolbar toolbar ;


    /*searching/filteration query*/
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener OnQuerySearchView = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//            if (searchCheck) {
            Log.i("Recycler query", arg0);

//            Fragment frag = new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),context).getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            PageAdapter adapter = ((PageAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter());
            Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            return false;
        }
    };

    public SlidingTab() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_tab, container, false);
         viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), context));
        slidingTab = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        searchview = (SearchView)v.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(OnQuerySearchView);
        return v;
    }
```

**PageAdapter.class**

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "PageAdapter";
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"New", "In Progress", "Completed"};
    private Context context;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "New Instance Created :" + position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new JobFragment();

            case 1:
                return new InProgressJobFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CompletedJobFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }


}
```

**Fragment RecyclerView Adapter (Call by each fragment in view pager and have searchview filter method)**

```
public class JobAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "EMPLOYEE ADAPTER";
    private static final int VIEW_NORMAL = 0;
    private ArrayList<Info> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<Info> filterList;
    private Context mAct;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        }
    }

    public void addApplications(ArrayList<Info> candidates) {
      }

    public void clearApplications() {
     }

    public JobAdapter(ArrayList<Info> myDataset, Context context) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
        this.mAct = context;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.job_card_new, parent, false);
        ViewHolder fh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return fh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//      }



**//    *searching/filtration on List*/**
    public void filter(String charText) {
        filterList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            if(mDataset != null) {
                filterList.addAll(mDataset);
            }
        } else {
            if (mDataset != null){
                for (Info wp : mDataset) {
                    if(wp.jobNumber !=null){
                        if(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(charText), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(wp.jobNumber).find()){
//                    if (wp.heading1.toLowerCase().contains(charText.toLowerCase())) {
                            filterList.add(wp);
                        }}else{

                    }

                    this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, filterList.size());

                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

> Please help me in implementing searchview in viewpager .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help of uploaded code
I can tell that

make method in your fragments named search and 
call adapter filter method

```
public void search(String text)
{
adapter.filter(text)
}
```

you can check instance of fragment and call search method of fragment after this line

```
 Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: i am exactly doing that . public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String arg0) {
            Log.i("Recycler query", arg0);

            int id = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            PageAdapter adapter = ((PageAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter());
            Fragment fragment = adapter.getFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            if(fragment instanceof JobFragment){
                ((JobFragment) fragment).recycleAdapter.filter(arg0);
            }But i am getting error : calling filter method on NULL Object.

Comment: no still not working . My Adapter coming null everytime i call .

Comment: can you upload code of JobFragment class ? so I can check that why adapter coming null

Comment: I accepted your answer as it really helped .Thanks a ton . Also , would be greatful if you upvote the question .

Comment: @yound_08 Any time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best design for this is to use the `Activity` as the central "hub" for events that need to go the fragments.

So this is how I would do this:

- First start with a listener interface.  This can be declared as an inner interface of the `Activity`:

  ```
  static interface QueryListener {

      void onQueryChange(String query);
  }
  ```
- Activity gets properties for holding listeners and methods for adding and removing listeners (declared synchronized to prevent those pesky `ConcurrentModificationException`s:

  ```
  private List<QueryListener> mQueryListeners = new ArrayList<>();

  public synchronized void addQueryListener(@NonNull QueryListener listener) {

     // check if the listener was already added
     // you could also use a Set instead of a List for this
     if (mQueryListeners.contains(listener)) return;   

     mQueryListeners.add(listener);
  }

  public synchronized void removeQueryListener(@NonNull QueryListener listener) {
      mQueryListeners.remove(listener);
  }
  ```
- Activity also gets a method that can be called by the fragment with the `SearchView`:

  ```
  public synchronized void changeQuery(String query) {

          for (QueryListener listener : mQueryListeners) {
              listener.onQueryChange(query);
          }
  }
  ```
- Now your fragments with the adapters need to implement `QueryListener` and register/unregister themselves:

  Add this line somewhere in `onCreate()`:

  ```
          ((YourActivity) getActivity()).addQueryListener(this);
  ```

  Unregister in `onDestroy()`:

  ```
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
          ((YourActivity) getActivity()).removeQueryListener(this);
          super.onDestroy();
      }
  ```

  add the QueryListener method implementation:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onQueryChange(String query) {

      // if (isVisible()) {      if desired
      mAdapter.filter(query);
  }
  ```

  Note: You don't have to have the fragment implement `QueryListener`; you can use an anonymous class.  But you'll have to hold the reference to it so you can call `removeQueryListener()` with it later.
- Now just hook up the `SearchView`:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

      ((YourActivity) getActivity()).changeQuery(query);
  }
  ```

Another pattern I've used is to create a dedicated class for registering/notifying listeners.  I create a single instance of this class and have a method on the Activity to access it:

```
        QueryHandler handler = ((YourActivity) getActivity()).getQueryHandler();
        // QueryHandler has all the listener properties and methods shown for the Activity

        ...

        handler.changeQuery(query);
```

Alternatively, you can also use one of the many open-source event bus packages like Otto to pass events amongst your fragments.